# How can I read a file in django template on client side

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to read some text from each file in django template.

My view is sending a list of files (after fetching it from database ) and I want to display first 250 characters of these files in the template.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Django is pure Python.  This is something that helps to remember when using the Templates.

Just read the file, and send it to the template as context.

Example:

```
def myview(request):
    context = {file: open('myfile.txt', 'r').read()[:250]}
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

That should do the trick.  You may need to add some extra formatting to the file before rending it.  You can add this to the template to get linebreaks in the file to render:

```
{{ file|linebreaks }}
```